# How to make durandal route relative

Tags: durandal, durandal-navigation

I am building a dynamic route base on user click, the navigationmodal is rebuilt after the user click a button, which determines the route to navigate the user to. How do I make durandal route relative when using the navigate in a view model. When I use the router.navigationmodel all the routes are configure as a relative to the current route, which is working fine. But when I try to use navigate in the viewmodel this remove the current route in the address bar and replace it with the string of the route I'm navigating to. 
For example:
using navigationmodel 
route -> 'car' the route display -> 'index#car' -> this is fine

but in the viewmodel, calling car with navigate('car') the route becomes -> '/car';

Please I will greatly appreciate it if someone can help with a solution.

Comment: Why not just call the active instruction and append 'car' onto it?

Comment: Thanks @PW Kad, I think the problem was because I was deactivating the router and reseting router in viewmodel, that actually clears  all the routes. But what I wanted was to set a route nav to true so that can be display, but since nav is not observable I needed to rebuild the routes, that clears all the routes. Please is there a way to rebuild the router without clearing the route in the history. thanks